# C++ using vector iterator correctly

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++ and I have a vector of doctors.
I add a new doctor with the following code:

```
void DoctorAdmin::setDoctor(std::string lastname, std::string forename,
 Person::Sex sex){

    //Create new doctor
    Doctor* doc = new Doctor(lastname, forename, sex);

    //insert at the end of the vector
    doctors.push_back(doc);
}
```

Then I want to show their information on the console:

```
void DoctorAdmin::showDoctors(){

cout << "Doctors:" << endl;
cout << "Name" << "\t\t\t" << "Forename" << "\t\t\t" << "Sex" << endl;

for (vector<Doctor*>::iterator i = doctors.begin(); i != doctors.end(); i++){

    Doctors* doc = doctors.at(i);
    cout << doc->getName() << "\t\t\t" << doc->getForename() << "\t\t\t" 
         << doc->getSex() << endl;
}
```

After doing it like this I get two Errors:

```
E0304   No instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::at [mit _Ty=Doctors *, _Alloc=std::allocator<Doctors *>]" matches the argument list.

// and

C2664   "Doctors *const &std::vector<Doctors *,std::allocator<_Ty>>::at(const unsigned int) const" : cannot convert from Argument "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>" in "const unsigned int"
```

How do I use the vector iterator correctly to avoid this?

Comment: `v.at(i)` is just a safer version of `v[i]` (it'll throw if `i` is out of bounds) which expects an integer. An iterator is some kind of "abstract pointer", what you want to write is `*i` instead of `aerzte.at(i)`

Comment: `Arzt* doc = *i;`. But you really should be using `vector<Arzt>` instead of `vector<Arzt*>` and forget about `new`.

Comment: unrelated: don't write your instances and class names in your native language, especially if you seek help in the international community. Plus you cannot write correct german without non-ascii characters.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, bitte achte das nächste mal darauf, das auch die Variabelnamen in englisch sind. Sonst wird es manchmal schwierig den Sinn zu verstehen *für die Anderen* ;)

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An iterator is not index-like, it is pointer-like.

```
for (vector<Arzt*>::iterator doc = aerzte.begin(); doc != aerzte.end(); doc++)
{
    cout << (*doc)->getName() << "\t\t\t" << (*doc)->getVorname() << "\t\t\t" 
         << (*doc)->getGeschlecht() << endl;
}
```

It seems like you are confused as to when you need to `new` things too. Most of the time you *don't need `new`*

```
vector<Arzt> aerzte;

void ArztAdmin::anlegenArzt(std::string name, std::string vorname, Person::Geschlecht geschlecht){
    // Create new doctor at the end of the vector
    aerzte.emplace_back(name, vorname, geschlecht);   
}
```

You can also directly bind references as loop variables

```
for (Arzt & doc : aerzte)
{
    cout << doc.getName() << "\t\t\t" << doc.getVorname() << "\t\t\t" 
         << doc.getGeschlecht() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Using `auto` in range-for would make things more convenient: `for ( auto& doc : doctors ) { ... }`.

Comment: @Azeem `auto` on its own would copy, and `auto &` is not shorter than `Arzt`

Comment: @Caleth At first glance had the same thought, but `auto` covers, too, the case of the class being renamed (e. g. to an English name)...

Comment: Caleth: You are right about the length of the type but I was thinking along the lines of AAA (Almost Always Auto) idiom (https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Answer (score 1):

The `at` function requires an index, but a `vector<Arzt*>::iterator` is not an index, neither semantically nor technically. **An iterator points directly to an element**, whereas an index represents the distance between a container's start and the element in a container that allows random element access.

Because an iterator points directly to an element, the `at` function isn't even necessary in your loop. `*i` yields the element:

```
Arzt* doc = *i;
```

Beginning with C++11, the code for such simple loops can be written in a shorter way using `auto`:

```
for (auto i = aerzte.begin(); i != aerzte.end(); i++){
```

The compiler knows what type `i` really is because it knows what `begin()` returns.

Even better, use a range-based loop:

```
for (auto doc : aerzte){
    cout << doc->getName() << "\t\t\t" << doc->getVorname() << "\t\t\t" 
         << doc->getGeschlecht() << endl;
}
```

And while we're at it, don't use dynamic memory allocation when you don't have to. This isn't Java or C#; `new` is dangerous territory in C++ and should be avoided:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Arzt
{
    Arzt(std::string const& name, std::string const& vorname) :
        name(name),
        vorname(vorname)
    {
    }

    std::string name;
    std::string vorname;
    // Geschlecht omitted for brevity's sake
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Arzt> aerzte;

    Arzt doc1("foo", "bar");
    Arzt doc2("foo", "bar");
    Arzt doc3("foo", "bar");

    aerzte.push_back(doc1);
    aerzte.push_back(doc2);
    aerzte.push_back(doc3);

    for (auto const& arzt : aerzte)
    {
        std::cout << arzt.name << ' ' << arzt.vorname << '\n';
    }
}
```

As you are no longer iterating over pointers but over larger objects, `const&` should be used in the `for` loop.